# Why change of gibbs energy per mole is zero at equilibrium?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, equilibrium

I was reviewing this concept and thought of this: $\frac{dG}{dt} = \frac{\partial G}{\partial \xi}\frac{d \xi}{d t}$, for a reaction to be at equilibrium  $\frac{d G}{d t}$ must be zero but I have seen in the formula $\Delta G_r=\Delta G^o_r+RT\ln(Q)$ , the condition for equilibrium is $\Delta G_r=\frac{d G}{d \xi}=0$. My question is, why is necessary $\Delta G_r=0$ to be in equilibrium if it's enough $\frac{d \xi}{d t}$ is zero and that make $\frac{d G}{d t}=0$ ? Is there an explanation of this phenomenon?

Comment: See [What exactly is minimized when we say that the Gibbs Free Energy of Reaction is minimized at equilibrium?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/719279) on Physics.SE. Note that Gibbs is the scientist's name, and math operators (`\ln`) as well as text labels (`\Delta_\mathrm{r}G^\circ`) should be upright.

Comment: What is $t$ here, if it is time it does not enter into classical thermodynamics, which only considers states at equilibrium.  $\xi$ is the extent of reaction so when the change of this with $G$ is zero (i.e. gradient zero) we are at equilibrium and $Q$ is replaced by $K_e$ the equilibrium constant. The extent of reaction is zero initially and $1$ when one mole is converted to product. At eqm $\Delta G_r^\text{o}=-RT\ln(K_e)$.

Comment: @porphyrin Thanks for replying, but you cannot describe the extent of reaction as a function of time and their initial reactants? then because a chemical reaction is not quasistatic it cannot be described with classical thermodynamics? I understood this well?

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand your comment, but using a rate equation of course allows [C] vs. t to be measured and so, eventually, an equilibrium constant. But classical thermodynamics does not involve time and only informs us about equilibrium states and changes in energy/entropy etc. in moving from one equilibrium state to another and not about how it happens.

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen, in the context of chemical reaction equilibria regarding classical thermodynamics, that the Gibbs free energy is a function of time.

For a single phase, open system, the total Gibbs energy is a function of the pressure, temperature, and moles of all the species $ G = G(P, T, n_1, n_2, ... n_N)$. Therefore, the total differential of the Gibbs energy is
$$ dG = VdP - SdT + \sum_j \mu_jdn_j \tag{1} $$
By stoichiometry, the moles of chemical species $ j $ can be written as $ n_j = n_{j,0} + \nu_j\varepsilon $, with $ \varepsilon $ defined as the **extent of reaction**. Thus, at constant pressure and temperature, the condition of chemical equilibrium states that Eq. (1) takes the form
\begin{align}
  dG &= \sum_j \nu_j \mu_j d\varepsilon  = 0 \\
  \dfrac{dG}{d\varepsilon} &= \sum_j \nu_j \mu_j = 0 \\
  \dfrac{dG}{d\varepsilon} &= \Delta_r G = 0 \\
\end{align}
And if you plug $ \mu_j = \mu_j^0 + RT \ln(\hat{f}_j/f_j^0) $ you end up with that equation you wrote
$$ \Delta_r G = \Delta_r G^0 + RT\ln \prod_j\bigg(\dfrac{\hat{f}_j}{f_j^0}\bigg)^{\nu_j} $$
$$ \Delta_r G = \Delta_r G^0 + RT\ln Q$$

So if you want to be systematic:

1. For a single chemical reaction at constant $P$ and $T$, chemical equilibrium reduces to $ dG/d\varepsilon = 0 $.
2. Some unknown author (at least to me) decided to call $ \sum_j \nu_j\mu_j = \Delta_r G $.
3. Solving $ \Delta_r G = 0$ means that you guarantee $ dG/d\varepsilon = 0 $.

The chain rule that you made there is mathematically fine, but in the context of **classical thermodynamics**, time is not a variable. If you want to know how things change in time, you resort to **kinetics**. Time may appear when solving transient balances. However, it is always explained that those jumps in time are between equilibrium states, that theoretically take an infinite amount of time. This is to guarantee that you can apply the thermodynamic relations, if not, you can't use them.

Thermodynamics will give you no information of the state of the system at a certain extent of reaction $ \varepsilon $. However, it will tell you that the extent of reaction will not vary when $ t\rightarrow\infty$, and will also give you that value $ \varepsilon=\varepsilon^\text{eq} $.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, I edited my question to fixed those partial derivatives and thanks for giving me the insight of the theorical amount of time needed for a reaction to be in equilibrium. However, that doesn't answer the question of why $\Delta_r G$ needs to be zero at equilibrium. I hope if you could clarify it. Thank you

Comment: At equilibrium, the Gibbs free energy has a minimum value, so in the context of a chemical reaction at a constant $P$ and $T$ this means that its derivative with respect to the extent of reaction is zero, i.e., $ dG/d\varepsilon = 0 $, or $ \Delta_r G = 0 $. It seems this is not the question. You want to know why at equilibrium the Gibbs free energy has a minimum value? Why we put a zero there?

Comment: Yes, that sounds a better way of phrasing, why Gibbs free energy has a minimum? Is there a principle behind this? Specifically why at equilbrium? Because the rate of extent of reaction approach to zero at equilibrium so I don't see why $\Delta_r G$ needs to be zero if it's enough with the reaction in forward and backward at equilibrium and the sum  of both individuals $\Delta G$ is zero because the rate of reaction of both reactions are the same and their respective $\Delta G$ cancelled each other.